# Change the Background color of the TitleBar in the Package.appxmanifest file

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I need to modify the background Color of the ApplicationViewTitleBar in my universal App,I did that in code Behind for each Class in my project like that:

```
ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
titleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;
```

I have a question please,
 - I have a Splashscreen defined in the
   Package.appxmanifest file,is there please any specified properties in this
   file I can use to modify the Background Color of the TitleBar when showing the Splashscreen

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do this using custom splash screen by extending page.similar to this sample
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187309.aspx
and other suggestion for you ,why to add all those five lines of title bar in every page you can use Behavior SDK or create static class with Dependency Properties.for more info see below link.
https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/easily-manage-the-title-bar-in-windows-10-apps/

Comment: Sir I have a problem,I have succefully displayed the costum splashscreen following your example,but I have a white page when I launch the app before the SplashScreen appears,any idea Sir How can I display automatically the splashsreen page when launching app

Comment: Ohh ,I guess that is default splash screen.I have no idea.